# .innerHTML doesn't understand variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

Finally i found a way to get div id from div class. But **.innerHTML** doesn't let me use javascript variables. It only understands exact div id, and i need to use div class (or other universal selector). What can i do?

```
xPosition = document.getElementById("xPosition"),

$(".box").on("mouseover", function(e){
var divid = e.target.id;

xPosition.innerHTML = divid._gsTransform.x;

});
```

._gsTransform.x is a part of greensock

Comment: `var divid = e.target.id;` - divid is a string ... a string has no _gsTransform property - `.innerHTML` isn't the problem ... `_gsTransform` is the problem

Comment: `getElementById()` and `e.target` both point to a DOMElement. Meaning you can just access the element without needing the id: `e.target._gsTransform.x`.

Comment: Oh shii Malk it's working 100%. Thank you so much!1